# multiple THREE.LOD objects all change state at same time

Tags: three.js

I'm designing a model of a city and want to implement LOD, based on this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lod

For testing purposes, I have loaded a subset of my buildings and created a LOD instance for each of them. 
The problem is that, they all seem to change state at the same time when I try to zoom in on one of them. I was expecting that the concrete building I was zooming towards would change state, but not those far away.

Here I create the LODs and add them to the scene

```
var geometries = [
    [ new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(rectShape, {steps: 2, amount: height, bevelEnabled: true, bevelSegments: 1, bevelSize: 0.1, bevelThickness: 0.1 }), 50 ],
    [ new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(rectShape, {steps: 1, amount: height, bevelEnabled: true, bevelSegments: 1, bevelSize: 0.1, bevelThickness: 0.1 }), 300 ],
    [ new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(rectShape, {steps: 0, amount: height, bevelEnabled: true, bevelSegments: 1, bevelSize: 0.1, bevelThickness: 0.1 }), 1000 ]
];

var materials = [
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: "rgb(255,0,0)" }),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: "rgb(0,255,0)" }),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: "rgb(0,0,255)" })
];


var lod = new THREE.LOD();
for (var i = 0; i < geometries.length; i ++ ) {
    //update
    geometries[i][0].computeBoundingBox();
    if(geometries[i][0].boundingBox.min.z<0){
            zDiff = geometries[i][0].boundingBox.min.z;
    }

    matrix.makeTranslation(-fCenterX,-fCenterY,-zDiff);
    geometries[i][0].applyMatrix(matrix);
    geometries[i][0].rotateX(-3.1415*0.5);
    //end update
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometries[ i ][ 0 ], materials[i] );
    mesh.updateMatrix();

    lod.addLevel( mesh, geometries[ i ][ 1 ] );

}

scene.add( lod );
```

As per the example, in my render():

```
scene.updateMatrixWorld();
scene.traverse(function(obj){
if(obj instanceof THREE.LOD){
        obj.update(camera);
    }
});

renderer.render(scene, camera);
rendererStats.update(renderer);
```

Am I ignorant of something obvious?

Comment: `lod.matrixAutoUpdate = false;` no ?

Comment: Already tried that.
I think it might have something to do with the fact that all the LODs are positioned at 0,0,0, while my geometries are positioned differently.
I have updated my code example with the complete code